# Can I set a dynamic cors policy which only allows specific origins to pass cookies (Node.js)?

Tags: node.js, express, cors

**Context**

I have an express server with two types of clients.

1. My app (React + graphql): I've enabled credentials for this client: `app.use(cors({ credentials: true, origin: "http://localhost:3000" }));` I've set this so that I can receive auth-related cookies from my gql client.
2. Third-party services (via http client I provide). These requests can come from any number of origins.

I can't use the wildcard operator for the orgin (`cors({origin: *})`) as this would allow any site to use my users' auth cookies. However, if I don't pass the wildcard operator, third-party clients can't make requests.

I've tried unsuccessfully to enable the wildcard on a specific route.

**Question**

Can I set different cors policies for different origins?

Comment: "react app of random origin"?  What are you trying to enable here?  Are you offering service that lots of other web-sites (unknown to you) will use?  If they are your own web-sites wouldn't you know the origins?

Comment: My server powers a dashboard (my app). I've also written a client that allows third-parties to call my service from their own React app. @jfriend00

Comment: What are these credentials?  I'm wondering if you can pass them in a different way?

Comment: @jfriend00 My understanding is that I need to pass `credentials: true` for the origin of my app so that it can send cookies. I can't set this origin to the wildcard for obvious reasons.

The error I'm encountering is thrown when I attempt to make a request from a mock-third party react app when the above policy is in place. Can't find a solution to this in the docs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a couple options.

1. You can set up a dynamic cors handler that will allow allow origins without using *.
2. You can get whatever is needed out of the cookie and pass it some other way (as a query parameter, for example).

You can write a programmatically controlled cors handler that can allow one domain, some domains, all domains, however you write the code.

Here's one that allows all domains without using *:

```
var corsOptions = {
  origin: function (origin, callback) {
    console.log(`Origin ${origin} is being granted CORS access`);
    callback(null, true)
  }
}

app.use(cors(corsOptions));
```

You don't have to apply this globally either.  You can apply it only to certain routes or only to certain routers.

Examples here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors in the CORS module documentation.

Comment: please.explain this code how it's working thanks

Comment: @QureshiOwais - I don't understand what you're asking.  You can examine the cors module code and see exactly what it does [here](https://github.com/expressjs/cors/tree/master/lib).

Comment: how this part work  ` origin: function (origin, callback) {
    console.log(`Origin ${origin} is being granted CORS access`);
    callback(null, true)
  }`

Comment: @QureshiOwais - Documentation [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors#configuration-options) with numerous examples of the callback on that page too.

Comment: Nice, i thought we can only do static array :)